# call function on the same controller nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following controller in nodejs with expressjs, I am trying to call a function in the same controller but I have the following error response **this.editarAluno is not a function**

**Controller**

```
var alunoController = {
  criarAluno: function (req, res) {
    this.editarAluno(req, res);
  },
  editarAluno: function (req, res) {
    console.log('Ok....');
  },
};

module.exports = alunoController;
```

Comment: Where is the code calling the method that is throwing the error?

Comment: Whenever you have `this` errors, the problem is most likely present where you call a function, not where you define it. Can you show us where you call `alunoController. criarAluno`?

Comment: I'm calling inside the route. router.post('/', security.isLoggedIn, alunoController.criarAluno);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd do it like this :

```
var alunoController = {
  criarAluno: function (req, res) {
    alunoController.editarAluno(req, res);
  },
  editarAluno: function (req, res) {
    console.log('Ok....');
  },
};

module.exports = alunoController;
```

Don't count on `this` but on `alunoController` because I think that `this` relates to `criarAluno`, not `alunoController`.

Comment: Okay, I'll take the test here now.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the response. @ dun32

Answer (score -2):

The Aluno Controller is an object ...

You should think to redefine how you construct your controller...

With the following code, the `this` is scope in the controller class.

```
class AlunoController {
  criarAluno(req, res) {
    this.editarAluno(req, res);
  }
  editarAluno(req, res) {
    console.log('Ok....');
  }
};

module.exports = new AlunoController();
```

Comment: `this` is the same in both cases. The OPs problem is most likely because they are invoking `criarAluno` and altering `this`

Comment: Okay, @candybeer, I'll take the test here now.

Comment: @EdeGerSil Just per curiosity, was it working for you ?

Comment: The calls to the controller would have to change for this type, so I did not follow this approach, but I did a standalone test on another project and it also works.